# How to instantiate an array of a member class in java

Tags: java, arrays, inner-classes

I have a class called MultiplePrintableInvoiceData, and this class has an inner class which is a member class called Product.

I can instantiate an instance of Product in another class with the following code:

```
MultiplePrintableInvoiceData pid = new MultiplePrintableInvoiceData();
MultiplePrintableInvoiceData.Product product = pid.new Product();
```

but when I try to instantiate an array of Product with the following code:

```
MultiplePrintableInvoiceData.Product[] product = pid.new Product[];
```

I get a compilation error: "(" expected - illegal start of expression. Please I need help.

**Update**
I have modified the code to:

```
MultiplePrintableInvoiceData.Product[] product = pid.new Product[11];
```

But it is still giving me an error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not possible to create an object of the *inner* class unless we already have an object of the 
*outer* class. This is because the object of the *inner* class is quietly connected to the object of the *outer* class that it was made  from. However, if you make a  nested class (a **static** inner class), then it doesn’t need a reference to the outer-class object.

However, This is not the case while creating an array of *inner* class. We can't  use Object of *outer* class for referencing to inner class while creating Array of inner class. because, we are not creating any *inner* objects. We are only creating an array, which is just a place to put *inner* objects. It does not need to belong to any *outer* objects.

```
  class Outer
  {
      class Inner
      {
        // field declaration and other code
      }
  }
  //...........
  Outer outerObj = new Outer();
  Outer.Inner innerObj = outerObj.new Inner(); // instance creation of inner class

  Outer.Inner[] innrArr = new Outer.Inner[5]; // array creation of inner class
```

For your context, You need to do:

```
MultiplePrintableInvoiceData.Product[] product = new MultiplePrintableInvoiceData.Product[10];
```